# How do I execute the same function across several tabs in one google sheets workbook?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to execute a simple copy paste script across 30 tabs in the same workbook.

Workbook layout - there is one tab for each of the 30 NBA teams--each tab named as a different team--alongside three other summary tabs (so 33 total). The format of each of the team-specific tabs is identical. The values in the cells are unique to the team's tab but column G, for ex, is the "home team" in each of the 30 team-tabs.

Goal - I'm trying to copy column D and paste it in column F within each team tab across the workbook. My thought was I would write the script for each tab, then string them together across the workbook. Below is what I have for the Mavericks:

```
function primeMavericks() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Mavericks');
 var rg=sh.getRange('D3:D33');
 var vA=rg.getValues();
 var tsh=ss.getRange('F3:F33');
 tsh.setValues(vA);
}
```

Problem - This works fine for one team but the second I start stringing in functions for other teams, the script starts to paste data from column D into tabs for different teams. For ex, below pastes column D from the Lakers into column F for the Clippers. If I string in the other 28 teams, it becomes absolute chaos..

```
function primeLakers() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Lakers');
 var rg=sh.getRange('D3:D33');
 var vA=rg.getValues();
 var tsh=ss.getRange('F3:F33');
 tsh.setValues(vA);
 primeClippers();
}

function primeClippers(){
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Clippers');
 var rg=sh.getRange('D3:D33');
 var vA=rg.getValues();
 var tsh=ss.getRange('F3:F33');
 tsh.setValues(vA);
}
```

I thought it might be because my variables have the same names (despite being nested in different functions). As an attempted fix, I went back and made each of the variable names unique and still ran into the same copy/paste issue.

I have no idea what to do here.. is there a better way to run this script that will get the intended result?

Comment: How are you executing the functions? onEdit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a for loop to iterate over the sheets. If you want to exclude specific tabs, you can do it with a conditional. Something like this should works:

```
function NBA (){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i=0; i < sheets.length; i++){

    if (sheets[i].getName() == "sheetToExclude"){
      continue;
    }
    var rg = sheets[i].getRange('D3:D33');
    var vA = rg.getValues();
    var tsh = sheets[i].getRange('F3:F33');
    tsh.setValues(vA);
  }
}
```

[For - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for)

Comment: Hello @Juan! I think your code has a slight error: the line `var tsh = ss.getRange('F3:F33');
` should be `var tsh = sheets[i].getRange('F3:F33');` instead, since you're getting the values from each specific sheet. Cheers!